# g-5 2005 or 2006 is dual core intel

Tags: snow-leopard

a 2005 or 2006 G-5 dual core a intel can snow lep be loaded on it or is quad core intel can snow lep be loaded thanks just need to no the answer

Comment: What type of Mac do you have here, an PPC/G5 or an Intel model?

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's Support Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4949):

**Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard system requirements**

To install Snow Leopard for the first time, you must have a Mac with:

- An Intel processor
- An internal or external DVD drive, or DVD or CD Sharing
- At least 1 GB of RAM (additional RAM is recommended)
- A built-in display or a display connected to an Apple-supplied video card supported by your computer
- At least 5 GB of disk space available, or 7 GB of disk space if you install the developer tools